# Symfony2 Doctrine use wrong alias in SQL, login fails with "Authentication request could not be processed [...]"

Tags: symfony, authentication, doctrine

I am trying to make my own user bundle, and am currently struggling at the login phase, with the error message :

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

I'm kinda new to Symfony and am doing my best to learn as many aspects as possible, so please forgive me if I took the wrong path in defining stuff.

### Structure

I have currently 2 bundles, one for my app called ScoreboardBundle, and one dedicated to the authenticating mechanic called Pulsahr\UserBundle. I intend to make this bundle reusable in another of my projects.
The User entity I want to use is ScoreboardBundle\Entity\User, and inherits from Pulsahr\UserBundle\Entity\User, which implements UserInterface, \Serializable.

### Log info

I looked into the dev.log, and found this intriguing line :
[2016-09-22 14:16:19] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.id AS id_2, t1.username AS username_3, t1.password AS password_4, t1.roles AS roles_5, t1.email AS email_6, t1.config AS config_7, t1.name AS name_8, t1.avatar AS avatar_9, t1.graph_color AS graph_color_10 **FROM user t1 WHERE t0.username** = ? LIMIT 1' with params [\"fdsfgsd\"]

I probably made a mistake somewhere, Doctrine is looking for an t0.username without defining the t0 alias. Why is that ?

Below are several of my files, hope it will help.
/src/Pulsahr/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml :

```
Pulsahr\UserBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: user
repositoryClass: Pulsahr\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    username:
        type: string
        length: 255
        unique: true
    password:
        type: string
        length: 255
    roles:
        type: array
        nullable: true
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

/src/ScoreboardBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml :

```
ScoreboardBundle\Entity\User:
type: entity
table: user
repositoryClass: ScoreboardBundle\Repository\UserRepository
fields:
    email:
        type: string
        length: 255
    config:
        type: integer
    name:
        type: string
        length: 127
    avatar:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
    graphColor:
        column: graph_color
        type: string
        length: 255


manyToMany:
    races:
        targetEntity: Race
        mappedBy: users

oneToMany:
    scores:
        targetEntity: Score
        mappedBy: user
lifecycleCallbacks: { }
```

/app/config/security.yml :

```
security:
encoders:
    ScoreboardBundle\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 4

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_RACEADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_RACEADMIN
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    pulsahr_userbundle:
        entity:
            class:    ScoreboardBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    pulsahr_user_security:
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            login_path: pulsahr_user_login
            check_path: pulsahr_user_check
        provider:  pulsahr_userbundle
        logout:
            path: pulsahr_user_logout
            target: pulsahr_user_login
        pattern: ^/
        remember_me:
            secret: '%secret%'
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I had to manually enter a user, and used a [bcrypt calculator](https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator) for the password, using 4 as cost, as same as defined in security.yml. But whatever the login and password used, I have the same error message.

Comment: Your yml file also has single quotes on the 'email' and 'name' length properties - remove the single quotes, as they are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many struggles, a friend helped me find a solution.
The problem was caused by inheritance on ScoreboardBundle\User\Entity\User from Pulsahr\UserBundle\Entity\User.
The php classes are fine, the problem comes from mapping. I had to specify in the User.orm.yaml that the origin class is a type "mappedSuperclass". By doing only this:

```
Pulsahr\UserBundle\Entity\User:
type: mappedSuperclass
table: user
[...]
```

More info on Doctrine documentation : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html
I hope this will help some people stuck like me.